# Npm rebuild node-sass fails

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-sass

I have an old project that has a grunt as build tool. I have installed the project dependencies and grunt cli. This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

On trying to run grunt I got an error that I need to run `npm rebuild node-sass`, but I got a new error then:

> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall script 'node
>   scripts/build.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of
>   node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a
>   problem with the node-sass package, npm ERR! not with npm itself.

I have even tried with running the command with the `--force flag`.
But that didn't work either, how can I fix this?

Comment: If on windows, you'll need [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools), else check [troubleshooting](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md)

Comment: What version of Node are you running? That is a very old version of node-sass that probably won't support beyond Node 4